# Getting .Spe file into array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to get python to import a file from my local computer. So I for my PHY class, I did an experiment where I used the software Maestro to record gamma radiation spectrum data from radioisotope samples, which produced data as counts vs channels. I have the data saved onto my computer as "Gamma Spectrum Calibration.Spe" I need to be able to put counts into an x axis array and channels into a y-axis array, but I've never done this before. I found an np.genfromtxt command but that doesnt work. Someone please help!

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.integrate import quad 


import math 
from scipy.constants import c, h, k, sigma

x = np.genfromtxt("Gamma Spectrum Calibration.Spe", dtype=None)
print(x[0])


#plt.plot([x], [y], marker='o', markersize=3, color="red")
#plt.title('Gamma Radiation Calibration: channel vs energy')
#plt.xlabel('Energy (keV)')
#plt.ylabel('Channel (arb. units)') 

plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(3)
plt.close()
```

Comment: `genfromtxt` is for `csv` files, text with neat rows and columns.

Comment: A bit of web search gives: `SPE file extension - Princeton Instruments CCD camera bitmap image`.  Python/numpy does not have a reader for this format, but there might well be third party loader.